# $filter on schema extensions microsoft graph doesn't support 'contains'

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I added a schema extension to users in my org, to keep track of training a user has taken. Since lists are not supported I am trying to store this as a comma separated string, as follows:

```
{
  "id": "voctestextension",
  "description": "voc test extension",
  "targetTypes": ["User"],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "trainings",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, while trying to fetch the users who have taken training 'X' I am making the below call:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=contains(extrw7rtbc9_voctestextension/trainings, 'Azure'), $select=extrw7rtbc9_voctestextension,displayName`

This doesn't give the correct response, but throws this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported Query.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "dc3fda19-6464-43d9-95ce-54a0567bf5a9",
      "date": "2018-03-15T09:14:30"
    }
  }
}
```

From different forum answers, I understand that `contains` is not supported. Can you suggest a better way to track this info in the user's profile?

Comment: This isn't a good use case for Extensions. Even if it could do a `contains` filter, you would be limited to a single 256 character string.

Answer (score 1):

Contains is not supported. You need to use startswith or add multiple properties like training1, training2, training3.. and then use filter with ORs and EQs.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter(extrw7rtbc9_voctestextension/trainign1 eq 'Azure' or extrw7rtbc9_voctestextension/trainign2 eq 'Azure')
```

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing, but couldn't get it work. How did you get the 'extrw7rtbc9' part for the query string?

Comment: It's the schema extension name. If random string if you don't have vanity domain name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups#2-register-a-schema-extension-definition-that-describes-a-training-course

Answer (score 0):

Kepaas solution is working (almost) perfectly, but the "=" is missing after "$filter":

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=(extrw7rtbc9_voctestextension/trainign1 eq 'Azure' or extrw7rtbc9_voctestextension/trainign2 eq 'Azure')
```